# Google Maps API V3 : How show the direction from a point A to point B (Blue line)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have latitude and longitude for 2 points on database, I want my Google Map to display a route from point A to point B...

Just like we see [here](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Pushpanjali,+Pitampura,+New+Delhi,+Delhi,+India/Rithala+Metro+Station,+Rithala+Rd,+Sector+12,+Rohini,+New+Delhi,+Delhi,+India/@28.7067137,77.1029945,14z/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x390d03fa8f749ecf:0x92cd7d17df1b6531!2m2!1d77.1102088!2d28.694143!1m5!1m1!1s0x390d014c11fcbee5:0x48f0136e99ecc5e2!2m2!1d77.107165!2d28.720783?hl=en) (Google Maps Directions)

[image: Image from the link]

How to draw that direction line on map ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use [directions service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Directions) of Google Maps API v3. It's basically the same as directions API, but nicely packed in Google Maps API which also provides convenient way to easily render the route on the map.

Information and examples about rendering the directions route on the map can be found in [rendering directions section](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#RenderingDirections) of Google Maps API v3 documentation.

Comment: @Tomik is it possible for the code to take a Image snapshot after the line had been drawn?

Comment: Please look at the second example: there is code :)

Answer (score 43):

### Using Javascript

I created a working demo that shows how to use the Google Maps API Directions Service in Javascript through a

- `DirectionsService` object to send and receive direction requests
- `DirectionsRenderer` object to render the returned route on the map

```js
function initMap() {
  var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.7519, -1.2578),
    pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8429, -0.1313),
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: pointA
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: map
    }),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointA,
      title: "point A",
      label: "A",
      map: map
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointB,
      title: "point B",
      label: "B",
      map: map
    });

  // get route from A to B
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);

}



function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

initMap();
```

```css
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #map-canvas {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Also on Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/u9no8te4/

### Using Google Maps Web Services

You can use the Web Services using an API_KEY issuing a request like this:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=API_KEY

An API_KEY can be obtained in the Google Developer Console with a quota of 2,500 free requests/day.

A request can return JSON or XML results that can be used to draw a path on a map.

Official documentation for Web Services using the Google Maps Directions API are [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

Comment: Hey i'm  using this code and its working fine,but i want to add one more marker A to C with different direction ,i'm trying many ways but isn't working

Comment: I am pretty new to google maps API, its working for me but how can i have a distance with the route?

Comment: @Sarz take a look at this other demo I made http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/fLogwsff/

Answer (score 20):

In your case here is a implementation using [directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions).

```
function displayRoute() {

    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(28.694004, 77.110291);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(28.72082, 77.107241);

    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();// also, constructor can get "DirectionsRendererOptions" object
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map); // map should be already initialized.

    var request = {
        origin : start,
        destination : end,
        travelMode : google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); 
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: For completeness, add this to the code: var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

Comment: Thanks @Dabbler, I have edited , 
fell free to edit if you see mistakes in answers.

Comment: is it possible for the code to take a Image snapshot after the line had been drawn?

Comment: I am not sure whether or not "directions service" provides that kind of functionality ((

Comment: good answer! Though, multiple click for directions product B points for each clicked - how do you reset the route/markers? :)

Answer (score 6):

```
  // First Initiate your map. Tie it to some ID in the HTML eg. 'MyMapID'
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('MyMapID'),
    {
      center: {
        lat: Some.latitude,
        lng: Some.longitude
      }
    }
  );
  // Create a new directionsService object.
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsService.route({
      origin: origin.latitude +','+ origin.longitude,
      destination: destination.latitude +','+ destination.longitude,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          suppressMarkers: true,
          map: map,
          directions: response,
          draggable: false,
          suppressPolylines: true, 
          // IF YOU SET `suppressPolylines` TO FALSE, THE LINE WILL BE
          // AUTOMATICALLY DRAWN FOR YOU.
        });

        // IF YOU WISH TO APPLY USER ACTIONS TO YOUR LINE YOU NEED TO CREATE A 
        // `polyLine` OBJECT BY LOOPING THROUGH THE RESPONSE ROUTES AND CREATING A 
        // LIST
        pathPoints = response.routes[0].overview_path.map(function (location) {
          return {lat: location.lat(), lng: location.lng()};
        });

        var assumedPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
         path: pathPoints, //APPLY LIST TO PATH
         geodesic: true,
         strokeColor: '#708090',
         strokeOpacity: 0.7,
         strokeWeight: 2.5
       });

       assumedPath.setMap(map); // Set the path object to the map
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/).

Make an ajax call i.e.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?parameters
```

and then parse the responce

Comment: is it possible for the code to take a Image snapshot after the line had been drawn?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a popup to show the map in a new window. I'm using the following url

```
https://www.google.com/maps?z=15&daddr=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
```

HTML snippet

```
<a target='_blank' href='https://www.google.com/maps?z=15&daddr=${location.latitude},${location.longitude}'>Calculate route</a>
```