# Google map count miles from start location to end location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am new with Google Map API. Now I have created bellow script to display direction from one location to another in Google map.

Now I want to get distance in `miles` and `kilometers`

I will appreciate if someone will help me.

My Current Code Fiddle is: [My Google Map](http://goo.gl/mJ15mo)

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)? What have you tried? What difficulty are you having doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so maybe you might trace a route https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/services?hl=es&csw=1#Directions

But exists a similar reference it was published in a previous article [Google Maps API V3 : How show the direction from a point A to point B (Blue line)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959788/google-maps-api-v3-how-show-the-direction-from-a-point-a-to-point-b-blue-line)

Good luck !

Comment: Hey, in addition you can try to use a jquery plugin to help with the Google Maps usage http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/14-services/getroute-53
Good night ;)