# How to add directions to Google Map Api in java in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Does google provide such service that we can implement in android to allow them to navigate from 1 place to another instead of coding the algorithm ourselves. For example, google has a code that enables the go to my current location on a map, is there one for directions, if not what is the easiest way to approach this.

For example this code enables a button on the map to allow users to go to current location.

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer at StackOverflow exactly addresses your question

[Google Maps API V3 : How show the direction from a point A to point B (Blue line)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959788/google-maps-api-v3-how-show-the-direction-from-a-point-a-to-point-b-blue-line)