# Plotting a route and various stops inside a route using google map

Tags: google-maps

I have a web application where i have one route which has a list of stops with latitude and longitude information , i want to plot this route on google map with all stops being displayed using some icon or a circle.
I have gone through documentation but did not find any concrete example.Should i use polylines for such a use case

Comment: How many stops?  Do you have the route polylines as well as the stops?  Have you seen [the documentation on the directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)?

Comment: if you want to have a real route overlaying the streets, polylines will not be the thing you want, as they will directly connect the stops.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959788/google-maps-api-v3-how-show-the-direction-from-a-point-a-to-point-b-blue-line) is a similar questions with no stops in between. You can adapt the example adding a waypoints object to your request.

```js
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.694004, 77.110291)
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  displayRoute();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function displayRoute() {

  var start = new google.maps.LatLng(28.694004, 77.110291);
  var end = new google.maps.LatLng(28.72082, 77.107241);

  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); // also, constructor can get "DirectionsRendererOptions" object
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map); // map should be already initialized.

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: [{
      location: new google.maps.LatLng(28.64, 77.1),
      stopover: true
    }, {
      location: new google.maps.LatLng(28.66, 77.41),
      stopover: true
    }],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Waypoints in directions</title>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```