# How to make Google map with to and from text boxes in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

This code is showing auto complete addresses, but I want to show them on a map.
I want to add Google maps on my asp.net page by taking the From and To address from the auto complete text boxes.

Please Help me.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtPlaces'));
            var places2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtPlaces2'));
            google.maps.event.addListener(places,places2, 'place_changed', function () {
                var place = places.getPlace();
                var address = place.formatted_address;
                var latitude = place.geometry.location.k;
                var longitude = place.geometry.location.D;
                var mesg = "Address: " + address;
                mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
                mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
               // alert(mesg);
            });
        });
       
</script>

<span>Location 1:</span>
<input type="text" id="txtPlaces" style="width: 250px" /><br /><br />
<span>Location 2:</span>
<input type="text" id="txtPlaces2" style="width: 250px" />
```

Comment: show some code buddy!! what you have tried???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addListener` call seems to be invalid. The second argument have to be the event, and here you pass a dom element. So I suggest the following change (without testing by me) :

```
var from = null;
var to = null;

google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function() {
    from = places.getPlace();
});
google.maps.event.addListener(places2, 'place_changed', function() {
    to = places2.getPlace();
});

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(from == null) {
        alert("You have to select an origin");
    } else {
        if(to == null) {
            alert("You have to select a destination");
        } else {
            var start = from.geometry.location;
            var end = to.geometry.location;
            //Render the direction
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: would you please help me to draw route from first address to 2nd on Google map using lat,long from text boxes i have

Comment: do you want direction instruction or just the route ?

Comment: just route using lat long that are in my text boxes

Comment: there is already a post on SO : [http://stackoverflow.com/q/5959788/4682796](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5959788/4682796)

Comment: Is there any way to restrict user not to enter address unless Google suggestions in auto complete text boxes.This is my problem

Comment: You can use two javascript variables (_from_ and _to_ places) you will init with your `onPlaceChange` function. Then on your submit button you check if your two variables are initialized and then you will only use the direction script with those variables.

Comment: I don't have any button , i want to alert when address is selected from suggestion list or when is not selected or entered anything irrelevent

Answer (score 0):

Check [this autocomplete gmap example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) with its javascript and html codes.
You can easily change them with asp net tools if you wish.
Also [this autocomplete example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) fills the adress form.
This is [the documentation for auto compete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) for google map.
You can understand how properties work.I recommend you to go with google's examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
         <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

           <body>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>


           <script type="text/javascript">
             google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
             var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtfromaddress'));
             google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
             var place = places.getPlace();
             var address = place.formatted_address;
             var latitude = place.geometry.location.k;
             var longitude = place.geometry.location.D;
             var mesg = "Address: " + address;
             mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
             mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
             alert(mesg);
             });
             });
          </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
              google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
              var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txttoaddress'));
              google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
              var place = places.getPlace();
              var address = place.formatted_address;
              var latitude = place.geometry.location.k;
              var longitude = place.geometry.location.D;
              var mesg = "Address: " + address;
              mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
              mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
              alert(mesg);
              });
              });
           </script>
    <asp:Label id="lblfromaddress " runat="server"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox id="txtfromaddress"  Runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

  <asp:Label id="lbltoaddress " runat="server"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox id="txttoaddress"  Runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

In the code behind use (C#):

lblfromaddress .Text = "From adddress";

lbltoaddress .Text = "To adddress";