# Bypass Google Maps Directions limits

Tags: google-maps, directions, limits

I've to make a map with multiple directions but the API limit 10 directions by map.
So how can I bypass this? Is there any paying way to increase the limits?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show some code, I'm not really sure what you mean exactly by saying directions...

Comment: How are you using the directions service?

Comment: Related question: [Want to Display Direction Between 100 Address on Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337710/want-to-display-direction-between-100-address-on-google-maps)

Comment: Related question: [Google Maps API to get bus route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315347/google-maps-api-to-get-bus-route)

Comment: Yes I use directions service @geocodezip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Google limit to 10 request per second so when I get the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error code. I wait 1 sec and I redo the request.

I've found this function:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```