# Is there a way to increase the maximum allowed number of waypoints in Google Directions API?

Tags: rest, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-directions-api

I'm working with Directions API, trying to get the best route from one point, pass through another places and return to the origin. But the max waypoints the API allows me to put is 25, and I need 120 on average.

Is there a way to change this restriction? Or maybe another service that allows more than 25 waypoints?

Comment: A couple of examples in the answer to the question: [Google Maps API to get bus route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315347/google-maps-api-to-get-bus-route) and [Want to Display Direction Between 100 Address on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337710/want-to-display-direction-between-100-address-on-google-maps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to add more than 25 waypoints for Directions API.

However, there is an open feature request in Google's Issue Tracker which I suggest starring to increase visibility and subscribe to future notifications:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35824756

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Evan, Your answer was very helpful. Thank you too for correct all my misspellings

Comment: Glad to hear & happy to help! :)