# Display step by step Google map Direction

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

sorry for my bad english.
i looking for a solution to trace a route on a google map, display progressively street names when user move and read by TTS google map instructions.. (like a GPS)
I wish  to display the following instruction when the user approaches the previous instruction
My watchPosition function call geolocationSuccess function each movement, this is not a good solution

In my example i trace a route from my geolocation to Omaha beach museum Normandy France

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Geolocation and Google Maps API</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
  
  
      function geolocationSuccess(position) {
  var destination="49.366973,-0.882042";
        var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        var myOptions = {
          zoom : 16,
          center : userLatLng,
          mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        // Place the marker
        new google.maps.Marker({
          map: mapObject,
          position: userLatLng
        });
  
   direction = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map   : mapObject,
 suppressMarkers : true
  //  panel : panel // Dom element pour afficher les instructions d'itinéraire
  }); 
  
      if(userLatLng && destination){
        var request = {
            origin      : userLatLng,
            destination : destination,
            travelMode  : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING // Mode de conduite
        }

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); // Service de calcul d'itinéraire
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){ // Envoie de la requête pour calculer le parcours
            if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
                direction.setDirections(response); // Trace l'itinéraire sur la carte et les différentes étapes du parcours
            }
   var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
   for (var i = 0; i < myRoute.steps.length; i++) {

    console.log(myRoute.steps[i].instructions+' -> '+myRoute.steps[i].distance.value);
    }
   console.log(myRoute.steps[0].instructions)

   $("#route").html('Dans '+myRoute.steps[0].distance.value+' m '+myRoute.steps[0].instructions);
   readbyTTS(myRoute.steps[0].instructions);
   var follow = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
         
    geolocationSuccess(position);
   });
  
        });
       
      }
      }

      function geolocationError(positionError) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />";
      }

      function geolocateUser() {
        // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
          var positionOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
          };
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, positionOptions);
        }
        else
          document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API";
      }

      window.onload = geolocateUser;
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map {
        width: 800px;
        height: 600px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1></h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <p><span id="route"></span></p>
    <p id="error"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help
KilRoy

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Introduction), it is a service that calculates directions between locations using an HTTP request.

This service is generally designed for calculating directions for static (known in advance) addresses for placement of application content on a map; this service is not designed to respond in real time to user input.

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959788/google-maps-api-v3-how-show-the-direction-from-a-point-a-to-point-b-blue-line) for more information.