# Why polygon line shows far from road in google maps in android?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I draw a polygon between two latitude and longitude but polygon line shows far from road. [image: Polygon line is show far from road]

Like the picture above, blue polygon line shows far from road. Where polygon line is draw there is no road. Anyone can help me to draw right polygon between two latitude and longitude.

Thank you!

Comment: you have drawn a line between two points (lat/lng points) and not a line following the road. So I think it is working as expected

Comment: I want to draw route between two address.

Answer (score 1):

If you want draw a route between two address, you should use [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=en).

or relative to this post [google-maps-api-v3-how-show-the-direction-from-a-point-a-to-point-b-blue-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959788/google-maps-api-v3-how-show-the-direction-from-a-point-a-to-point-b-blue-line)