# What is the shortest way to display a "drivable" path between 2 coordinates in android using google maps api (any version)?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I have 2 coordinates (one of source and one of destination) , both of which keep changing every 5 seconds. I want to display path between these two points in android.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959788/google-maps-api-v3-how-show-the-direction-from-a-point-a-to-point-b-blue-line) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2). The first one appeared to be easy,because small code :). But it was using javascript. The second one however is for android and is quite intimidating for a begginer like me (Also it has not been edited for quite some time).

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

For routing between two coordinates you need to use online Apis. There is no Offline method.

Here is the Api :

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?language=fa&units=metric&mode=driving&origin=52.381215,4.9880833&destination=52.345784,4.832558](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?language=fa&units=metric&mode=driving&origin=52.381215,4.9880833&destination=52.345784,%204.832558)

it return you the json data and its to you to show the route on map.

language : its for the language of step by step routing
origin : source point
destination : destination point