# JavaScript - Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I copied the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959788/google-maps-api-v3-how-show-the-direction-from-a-point-a-to-point-b-blue-line) to try and get directions for two points. The point's markers and direction is shown. However, I get an error in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined` just want to know how to get rid of it.

Below is the JavaScript code that I got from the accepted answer on the above linked question.

```
function initMap() {
    var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.7519, -1.2578),
        pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8429, -0.1313),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: pointA
        },
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
        // Instantiate a directions service.
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            map: map
        }),
        markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointA,
            title: "point A",
            label: "A",
            map: map
        }),
        markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointB,
            title: "point B",
            label: "B",
            map: map
        });

    // get route from A to B
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);

}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: pointA,
        destination: pointB,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}

initMap();
```

Error Screen shot:

[image]
Thank you

Comment: When you open the network tab does the script request return the requested js file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `async defer`, on your google `script` tag, is making the google script load asynchronously (non-instantaneously).

While your script is loading and executing instantly. So, your script is referencing the google api even before it's loaded into the document.

Removing `async defer` will load the google script in normally, before yours, so you can be sure it will be available.

Comment: @Tobig Even after removing `async defer` I still get the same error?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a different error. I noticed the error after testing removing `async defer`. It would have to be a new question.

Comment: @BShaps The fact that I'm getting an API KEY error is proof the async problem is fixed, and the script is actually loading in...

Comment: I had and still have the same error, I have added a screen shot to the question which shows exactly where I get the error.

Comment: @i fixed the issue as I was calling the `initMap();` at the end of the script. After removing that the error has gone away. Thank you for your help

Comment: ...or you leave the `async defer` on the script tag and use the callback method: `<script src="...googleapi?callback=initMap"></script>` - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial